# Choppy exit when back button pressed

Tags: android, activity-finish, onbackpressed

I have implemented my app to exit when the back button is pressed. When I exit the app, I usually get a choppy exit where the recent apps displays before the app properly exits. What can be causing this issue? Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button discover,why,enterprise,business,services,office,inquire,connect;
TextView offer;
Intent p;
private static long back_pressed_time;
private static long PERIOD = 2000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    offer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.offer);
    discover = (Button) findViewById(R.id.discover_us);
    why = (Button) findViewById(R.id.why_us);
    enterprise = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterprise_soln);
    business = (Button) findViewById(R.id.business_soln);
    services = (Button) findViewById(R.id.services);
    office = (Button) findViewById(R.id.office_automation);
    inquire = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inquire);
    connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.discover_us:
             p = new Intent(this,DiscoverUs.class);
            startActivity(p);
            break;
        case R.id.why_us:
            p = new Intent(this,WhyTechbiz.class);
            startActivity(p);
            break;
        case R.id.office_automation:
            p = new Intent(this,Office_Automation.class);
            startActivity(p);
            break;
        case R.id.services:
             p = new Intent(this,Services.class);
            startActivity(p);
            break;

        case R.id.enterprise_soln:
            p = new Intent(this,Enterprise_Soln.class);
            startActivity(p);
            break;
        case R.id.business_soln:
            p = new Intent(this,Business_Soln.class);
            startActivity(p);
            break;
        case R.id.inquire:
            p = new Intent(this,Inquire.class);
            startActivity(p);
            break;
        case R.id.connect:
            p = new Intent(this,Connect.class);
            startActivity(p);
            break;
    }
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (back_pressed_time + PERIOD > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    super.onBackPressed();
} else {
    back_pressed_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think this piece of code is enough to track down your issue. Is there like something else ongoing in your `Acitivity` when you click Back button?

Comment: Please define _"choppy exit "_.

Comment: Choppy meaning it freezes mid closure of the app while showing the recent apps list then eventually exiting

Answer (score 1):

When you are finishing the activity just call also `super.onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (back_pressed_time + PERIOD > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        back_pressed_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Calling `finish()` is not a good choice to exit the activity, you could just use `super.onBackPressed()`.

Comment: Still no difference

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, your OS/Device must be slow.

If there's any other code which is getting executed from your onBackPressed() which you have not posted here, that might be cause else everything looks good.

Comment: Edited my code take a look. Can't be my phone since it has 3 gigs of RAM plus I tried it on different phones

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by setting windowIsTranslucent to false in my app theme.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should initialize back_pressed_time and set PERIOD =3000 last step this line should be top
back_pressed_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
So :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

back_pressed_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (back_pressed_time + PERIOD > System.currentTimeMillis()) this.finish();
    else Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```